How to format XML in Notepad++ without a plugin?
I would like to know if there is a way to format an XML without the plugin?
I know how to do it with the XML tools plugin but I usually don't have admin rights to install it so I would be very helpful to be able to format XML without it.

Ask your admin to install it.

... or  format manually...
